# How to import CSS file path instead of the entire file in react

Tags: css, reactjs, import

When we import an image in react, we get its file path in the directory, and we can directly link it in the `src` attribute of an `<img/>` tag like so:

`import some_icon from "../assets/images/some_icon"`

and then :

`<img src={some_icon}/>`

here, `some_icon` contains the path of the image that can directly be used in the src attribute.

In the same way, I want to import just the file path of a css file and not the styles of the file.

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: And after that how you are planning to use it?

Comment: After your import's you can simply do this, `const cssFilePath = "../assests/css/cssFile.css"`.

Comment: I am using Tiny MCE Editor and it accepts css file link in its init prop:
 `<Editor
                init={{
                    content_css: [
                        "https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,400,700"
                    ]
/>` 
I don't want to make a separate variable and hardcode the path.
 @ravibagul91

Comment: if you could use css paths like u described in your question, you kinda hardcode the path to the file as well (import statement). you have to specify your file at some point

Comment: @ravibagul91 Tiny MCE editor is a third party library which is not compatible with react. It accepts only absolute file paths and the solution you provided above ie storing the file path in a variable wont resolve to the absolute path. For it to work, i'll have to move the css file in public folder

Answer (score 1):

Yes just import like this:

```
import "../assets/css/style.css";
```

and then the style will auto apply to what you're selecting in your css file.

Comment: I am not concerned with the styles. I just wan't the css file path in a variable. Just like we do while importing images.

Comment: @ravibagul91 I have mentioned it in the comments of the question above.

Comment: @YoshitaArora, See my comment above, and let me know if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Your question implies you are using a React-based framework that has webpack inbuilt, probably Create React App.

When you use `import some_icon from "../assets/images/some_icon"`, what is actually happening is that the `image-loader` is going to fetch the image (some optimizations may occur where in some cases, a base-64 version of the image is fetched and in some cases the file is copied to the `build` folder and the new filename is used).

To get the CSS, I recommend importing like so `import "../assets/css/style.css";` This is better than importing in the HTML file because the CSS loader **may** combine all the CSS files used in the project and the output will be one giant CSS file.